# Docker on a Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have an odd situation. We use Wyse thin clients to remote into windows environemts (Windows 8 on an Intel Xenon E5-2640)

What I need to do is enable nested virtualisation, [as explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization) or used [here on a mac.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=docker%20on%20a%20virtual%20machine)

My task manager tells me I have Virtual processors and docker complains that hyper-V is not enabled, although it is.

How do you get docker to run on such a set up?

Comment: I'd suggest asking on SuperUser. This is unfortunately off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for the reference, the question already has an answer there! https://superuser.com/questions/1284866/running-docker-on-a-windows-2012-server-virtual-machine the blog   http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/11/run-hyper-v-docker-on-virtual-machine/  provides the steps to enable this